# paginated calls on a service method without changing signature of original method

Tags: java, lambda, pagination, java-8, mockito

I have a use case where I need to add pagination inputs (viz. page number and page size) to existing service calls (that returns a list of results) without changing the existing signature (because it will break existing clients). One way of achieving this is that we set the inputs in a threadlocal and have the implementation read the threadlocal and do its pagination logic. From a code point of view, it would look something like:

```
try {
    PaginationKit.setPaginationInput(pageSize, pageNumber); // Set threadlocal
    List<SpecialObject> results = specialService.getSpecialObjs(); //results count will be equal to pageSize value
} finally {
    PaginationKit.clearPaginationInput(); // Clear threadlocal
}
```

From a client's point of view, this is not at all elegant and I wanted to wrap this functionality into some better syntactic sugar. There were two approaches I had in mind and I wanted to know if this is a generic enough use case that has been solved as a pattern elsewhere. There are many such services and trying to put up a decorator for each of the services is not desirable.

Approach 1:
I like the mockito style of `Mockito.when(methodCall).thenReturn(result)` kind of sugar. 
So the code may look like:

```
SpecialService specialService = PaginationDecorator.prepare(SpecialService.class); // Get a spy that is capable of forwarding calls to the actual instance
List<SpecialObject> results = PaginationDecorator.withPageSize(pageSize).onPage(pageNumber).get(specialService.getSpecialObjs()).get(); // The get() is added to clear the threadlocal
```

I tried to borrow code from Mockito to create the spy, but the `OngoingStubbing<T>` interface is quite intertwined in the subsequent call chaining/creation code and is smelling of something that I should avoid.

Approach 2:
Use java.util.Function to capture the method call and accept two additional parameters pageNumber and pageSize to play with the threadlocals. The code may look like

```
List<SpecialObject> results = PaginationDecorator.withPaging(specialService.getSpecialObjs(), pageSize, pageNumber);
```

PaginationDecorator.java:

```
public static List<T> withPaging(Function<U, List<T>> call, int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
    try {
        PaginationKit.setPaginationInput(pageSize, pageNumber); // Set threadlocal
        return call.apply(); // Clearly, something is missing here!
    } finally {
        PaginationKit.clearPaginationInput(); // Clear threadlocal
    }
}
```

I am not able to clearly formulate how to use call correctly here.

Can someone please tell me :

- which of these two is the better approach
- if this is available as a recipe elsewhere using a different approach
- suggest ways forward to implement approach 1 or 2. Personally #2 seems cleaner to me (if it works).

Feel free to critique the approach and thanks in advance for the read!

P.S.: I also liked the [iterator recipe in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557837/paginated-queries-iterator-recipe), but the primary problem of syntactic sugar is still desired.

Comment: I'm sure the answer to this will be no, but can you just edit the signature of the existing methods, but provide overridden versions for the old clients which delegate to the method with pagination set at some defaults?

Comment: Yep, don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second variant does not work, because you are using the wrong interface (`Function` expects an input argument) and no syntax to create a function instance, but just an ordinary invocation expression.

You have several choices

1. Use `Supplier`. This interface describes a function without parameters and returning a value.

   ```
   public static <T> T withPaging(Supplier<T> call, int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
       try {
           PaginationKit.setPaginationInput(pageSize, pageNumber); // Set threadlocal
           return call.get();
       } finally {
           PaginationKit.clearPaginationInput(); // Clear threadlocal
       }
   }
   ```

   Instead of insisting on it to return `List<T>`, we simply allow any return type which raises its versatility. It includes the possibility to return a `List` of something.

   Then, we may use either, a method reference

   ```
   List<SpecialObject> results=PaginationDecorator.withPaging(
                       specialService::getSpecialObjs, pageSize, pageNumber);
   ```

   or a lambda expression:

   ```
   List<SpecialObject> results=PaginationDecorator.withPaging(
                       () -> specialService.getSpecialObjs(), pageSize, pageNumber);
   ```
2. Stay with `Function`, but allow the caller to pass the required argument

   ```
   public static <T,R> R withPaging(
       Function<T,R> call, T argument, int pageSize, int pageNumber) {

       try {
           PaginationKit.setPaginationInput(pageSize, pageNumber); // Set threadlocal
           return call.apply(argument);
       } finally {
           PaginationKit.clearPaginationInput(); // Clear threadlocal
       }
   }
   ```

   Now, the caller has to provide a function and a value. Since the intended method is an instance method, the receiver instance can be treated like a function argument

   Then, the function might be again specified either, as a (now unbound) method reference

   ```
   List<SpecialObject> results=PaginationDecorator.withPaging(
           SpecialService::getSpecialObjs, specialService, pageSize, pageNumber);
   ```

   or a lambda expression:

   ```
   List<SpecialObject> results=PaginationDecorator.withPaging(
           ss -> ss.getSpecialObjs(), specialService, pageSize, pageNumber);
   ```
3. There is an alternative to both, resorting to `AutoCloseable` and try-with-resource, rather than `try…finally`. Define the helper class as:

   ```
   interface Paging extends AutoCloseable {
       void close();
       static Paging withPaging(int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
           PaginationKit.setPaginationInput(pageSize, pageNumber);
           return ()->PaginationKit.clearPaginationInput();
       }
   }
   ```

   and use it like

   ```
   List<SpecialObject> results;
   try(Paging pg=Paging.withPaging(pageSize, pageNumber)) {
       results=specialService.getSpecialObjs();
   }
   ```

   The advantage is that this will not break the code flow regarding your intended action, i.e. unlike lambda expressions you may modify all local variables inside the guarded code. Recent IDEs will also warn you if you forget to put the result of `withPaging` inside a proper `try(…)` statement. Further, if an exception is thrown and another one occurs inside the cleanup (i.e. `clearPaginationInput()`), unlike `finally`, the secondary exception will not mask the primary one but get recorded via `addSuppressed` instead.

   That’s what I would prefer here.

Comment: Never mind, but the next time you start a bounty, keep in mind that you have an entire week to award it, so there’s no need for haste.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach seems cleaner and easier for this task. As for implementation you can just use Java's `Proxy` class. It seems easy enough. I don't know any libraries that somehow make it even more easier.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class PagingDecorator {
    public static void setPaginationInput(int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
    }

    public static void clearPaginationInput() {
    }

    public static <T> T wrap(final Class<T> interfaceClass, final T object, final int pageSize, final int pageNumber) {
        if (object == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument shouldn't be null");
        }

        ClassLoader classLoader = object.getClass().getClassLoader();
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, new Class[]{interfaceClass}, new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                setPaginationInput(pageSize, pageNumber);
                try {
                    return method.invoke(object, args);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw e.getTargetException();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw e;
                } finally {
                    clearPaginationInput();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static <T> T wrap(final T object, final int pageSize, final int pageNumber) {
        if (object == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument shouldn't be null");
        }

        Class<?>[] iFaces = object.getClass().getInterfaces();

        //you can use all interfaces, when creating proxy, but it seems cleaner to only mock the concreate interface that you want..
        //unfortunately, you can't just grab T as interface here, becuase of Java's generics' mechanic
        if (iFaces.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object implements more than 1 interface - use wrap() with explicit interface argument.");
        }

        Class<T> iFace = (Class<T>) iFaces[0];
        return wrap(iFace, object, pageSize, pageNumber);
    }

    public interface Some {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Some s = new Some() {};

        Some wrapped1 = wrap(Some.class, s, 20, 20);
        Some wrapped2 = wrap(s, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant by approach #2, but is quite nice! I think the other problem in using Java's proxy is that it only works on classes that have an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Java 8, right? Maybe you can add a default method without any implementation (sounds a litte weird, I know) like this:

```
// Your current service interface
interface ServiceInterface <T> {

    // Existing method
    List<T> getObjects();

    // New method with pagination atributes
    default List<T> getObjects(int pageSize, int pageNumber) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

The new services (with pagination suport) must override this method. In my opinion, this way You "keep it simple".

Comment: we need to continue to use the same service method and can't change the method signature.